# Как получить доступ ко всем данным по ключу из NSJSONSerialization на SWIFT

Tags: ios, json, swift

Имеется удаленный json :

> http://formatio.ru/api/v1/events?q=&city_id=&tag_id=&start_date=2015-01-01&end_date

Нужно стянуть его, а потом вывести в массив все данные по ключу "titile"

я прописал в функции override func viewDidLoad() 
следующее:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url)!)
    var jsonErrorOptional: NSError?
    let jsonOptional:AnyObject! =     NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &jsonErrorOptional)


    }
```

Теперь, как я понял, у меня есть объект класса NSJSONSerialization jsonOptional.
Как выбрать оттуда информацию по ключу "title"

Структура JSON:

> http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://formatio.ru/api/v1/events?q=&city_id=&tag_id=&start_date=2015-01-01&end_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typealias JSONObject = [String: AnyObject] // Это чисто для удобства и большей эстетичности в коде, делать это необязательно, тогда в коде ниже везде вместо JSONObject нужно использовать [String: AnyObject]

if let parsed = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: &jsonErrorOptional) as? JSONObject {
    if let eventsObjects = parsed["events"] as? [JSONObject] {

    }
}
```

и т.д.